# Setting up QGIS to work with Eclipse and Python

Tags: python, eclipse, qgis

I am following a recipe in "QGIS Python Programming Cookbook - Adding the python interpreter to windows".

I have a win10 64 systems with QGIS2.18 and Eclipse Oxygen.1a(4.7.1)

The problem is that when I try to set the Python interpreter for PyQGIS in Eclipse. Eclipse returns the following error message "unable to get info on the interpreter C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe"   The message suggests "using an unsupported version Python...require at least version 2.1...".

I checked and I am using Python version 2.7.5.

Can anyone suggest how I can resolve this issue?  I am guessing that there are some conflicts in the configuration of QGIS and or Python and or eclipse but I am at a loss as to what and how to find and fix the issue.   I can run python code in QGIS but with some issues.   For example I can create a memory vector layer but it doesn't appear on the map canvas as expected.

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230573/49538 ,the steps is the same if you have a QGIS normal instalation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is very specific. i don't think this error is occur due to your python version.

I was also getting the same error, but after visiting the following links error has been resolved.

I suggest you to please refer following link.

[Adding QGIS-specific Python interpreter to Eclipse?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183723/adding-qgis-specific-python-interpreter-to-eclipse)

[error solved  "unable to get info on the interpreter C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\python.exe"](https://tutel.me/c/gis/questions/256023/qgiscore+import+error+no+module+named+qgiscore#)

[A Quick Guide to Getting Started with PyQGIS on Windows](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2014/10/09/a-quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-on-windows/)